# How to add a column with given values to a Pandas dataframe, grouped by another column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two Pandas dataframes:

```
print(df_a)
   ID  irrelevant_value
0   1  1.2
1   1  2.3
2   1  0.9
3   1  1.1
4   2  2.7
5   2  3.1
6   3  1.3
7   3  0.2
8   3  2.3
...
```

and

```
    ID  add_these_values_to_the_same_ID
0   1   100
1   2   120
2   3   90
...
```

I would like to combine them, such that - desired result:

```
print(df_a)

    ID  irrelevant_value  add_these_values_to_the_same_ID
0   1   1.2               100
1   1   2.3               100
2   1   0.9               100
3   1   1.1               100
4   2   2.7               120
5   2   3.1               120
6   3   1.3               90
7   3   0.2               90
8   3   2.3               90
...
```

How can this be accomplished?

I have been struggling with df_a.groupby(["ID"]), but cannot find a way forward.

Comment: I would look up how to use joins or merges in pandas.  See the following links: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html 
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Comment: Yes! Thank you, kindly. This seems to be exactly what I needed: df_a = df_a.join(df_b.set_index("ID"), on="ID")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `groupby` function is not needed here; instead, just use [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html). As it says in those docs,

> If both key columns contain rows where the key is a null value, those rows will be matched against each other. This is different from usual SQL join behaviour and can lead to unexpected results.

And both of your dataframes contain `ID`. Therefore, you can merge the dataframes with this code (this is just one way to do so with one method, but it does work):

```py
import pandas as pd

# Example dataframes - these might be defined elsewhere in your situation
data_a = {'ID': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
          'irrelevant_value': [1.2, 2.3, 0.9, 1.1, 2.7, 3.1, 1.3, 0.2, 2.3]}
df_a = pd.DataFrame(data_a)

data_b = {'ID': [1, 2, 3],
          'add_these_values_to_the_same_ID': [100, 120, 90]}
df_b = pd.DataFrame(data_b)

# Merge dataframes on the 'ID' column
result = df_a.merge(df_b, on='ID')

print(result)
```

The really important line there is:

```py
result = df_a.merge(df_b, on='ID')
```

And this will output:

```
   ID  irrelevant_value  add_these_values_to_the_same_ID
0   1               1.2                             100
1   1               2.3                             100
2   1               0.9                             100
3   1               1.1                             100
4   2               2.7                             120
5   2               3.1                             120
6   3               1.3                              90
7   3               0.2                              90
8   3               2.3                              90
```

This should work, but if your data does not work with this method, you can take a look at `how`:

> `how{‘left’, ‘right’, ‘outer’, ‘inner’, ‘cross’}`, default `inner`
> Type of merge to be performed.
>
> - `left`: use only keys from left frame, similar to a SQL left outer join; preserve key order.
> - `right`: use only keys from right frame, similar to a SQL right outer join; preserve key order.
> - `outer`: use union of keys from both frames, similar to a SQL full outer join; sort keys lexicographically.
> - `inner`: use intersection of keys from both frames, similar to a SQL inner join; preserve the order of the left keys.
> - `cross`: creates the cartesian product from both frames, preserves the order of the left keys.

`outer` might work if the code above does not.

Comment: Beautiful! Your suggestions seems to work well, and looks nice and clean! Thank you for taking the time to explain.

Answer (score 0):

Try: [`dataframe.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

```
df_a.merge(other_df, left_on = 'ID', right_on = 'ID')
```